# Cannot start Azure Worker Role because System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel is in the Faulted state

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

This is from a local Visual Studio 2015 with Microsoft Azure Tools 2.9.

The full error message when starting the cloud service locally from VS is as follows:

> Microsoft Azure Tools: The communication object,
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for
>   communication because it is in the Faulted state.

I've tried running VS as Administrator, and also using Full Emulator (as I've seen other suggested), but to no avail.

Edit: Some additional information:

- This worked fine a couple of weeks ago, and I've not really updated anything on my PC since then (not even a Windows update)
- The same error occurs in VS 2017
- The same error occurs in other worker role projects
- This error occurs on my work PC; on my personal laptop running VS 2017 it works fine (it also runs fine for the other project members)

This makes me believe it has nothing to do with Visual Studio or the project files or configuration. But maybe something to do with the Windows 10 installation?

Comment: I would suggest you refer the troubleshooting steps: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sriharsha/2012/04/06/windows-azure-this-communication-object-system-servicemodel-channels-servicechannel-cannot-be-used-for-communication-because-it-is-in-the-faulted-state/  incase if you haven’t checked and see if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, I've already seen it. There's no Web.config in my project (since it's a worker role and not a web role), there's only 1 role instance, and the number of files is relative low. I've also checked the IISConfigurator folder (as they suggested), and it's empty.

Also, this worked perfectly fine a couple of weeks ago (was on sick leave, and when I got back I got this error message).

Comment: @Brakara - we're seeing the same issue, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I've just fixed this by right clicking the cloud service (in VS) and in the settings changing the mode from express -> full.

Comment: @DaveClarke No, I never managed to resolve it. I've already tried using full emulator mode, but the startup process just hangs then. But I've seen it work for others, and I'm glad it worked for you too. :)